# Django: "initial_value must be str or None, not bytes" error

Tags: python, django, pdf

While learning Django and Python I am trying to download a pdf file. The files content should be from a html template. I am trying to do this using the pisaDocument example(and any other example from the internet are exactyle the same). In my case I am getting the: `initial_value must be str or None, not bytes` error on the `StringIO(html.encode("utf-8"))` part. I understand that the problem is that StringIo need a str and it returns bytes, but how can i convert the bytes to str?

```
from django.http import HttpResponse, Http404
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.template.loader import get_template
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from io import StringIO, BytesIO
from cgi import escape

def export(request):
    if(request.POST):
        client = request.POST.get('client')
        doc = request.POST.get('doc')
        template = get_template('files/insurance.html.twig')
        html = template.render()
        result = StringIO(html)

        pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(StringIO(html.encode("utf-8")), result)
        if not pdf.err:
            return HttpResponse(result.getvalue(), content_type='application/pdf')
        return HttpResponse('We had some errors<pre>%s</pre>' % escape(html))
    else:
        raise Http404("POST data not found")
```

Comment: try `pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(StringIO(html), result)`.

Comment: Already tried that. Error: string argument expected, got 'bytes'